# apache customlog rotatelogs in server config section

Tags: apache

My particular situation is that I have a log file (for mod security) that I need it to be rotated every 5M.  I have several virtual webserver setup but, I'd like to have only one mod security log file for the entire instance and, rotate it every 5M.  I have the following line in my httpd.conf but, it is not rotating every 5M.  Here is what I have:

```
CustomLog "|/app/apache/bin/rotatelogs /app/apache/logs/modsec_audit1.log 5M" combined
```